# Destructor of one struct field depends on other without any correlation

Tags: rust, lifetime

I tried to make a short reproducible example but couldn't reproduce my problem, so I stripped most of the contents from my main code retaining the error.

**lib.rs**

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::{quote};
use syn::{
    parse_macro_input, Data, DeriveInput, Field, Fields, Ident,
    Type, TypeGenerics,
};

struct IterMapped<Ret, T: Iterator + Clone> {
    iter: T,
    map_func: Box<dyn FnMut(T::Item) -> Ret>,
}

impl<Ret, T: Iterator + Clone> IterMapped<Ret, T> {
    pub fn new(iter: T, map_func: Box<dyn FnMut(T::Item) -> Ret>) -> Self {
        IterMapped { iter, map_func }
    }
}

enum BuilderField<'a> {
    Optional(&'a Field, &'a Type),
    Mandatory(&'a Field),
}

struct BuilderData<'a> {
    struct_name: &'a Ident,
    builder_struct_name: &'a Ident,
    ty_generics: &'a TypeGenerics<'a>,
    fields_mapped_iter: IterMapped<BuilderField<'a>, syn::punctuated::Iter<'a, Field>>,
}

#[proc_macro_derive(Builder)]
pub fn derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let derive_input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);

    let data = &derive_input.data;
 
    let struct_name = &derive_input.ident;
    let (impl_generics, ty_generics_temp, where_clause) = derive_input.generics.split_for_impl();
 
    let fields_iter = match data {
        Data::Struct(ref data_struct) => match data_struct.fields {
            Fields::Named(ref fields_named) => fields_named.named.iter(),
            Fields::Unnamed(_) | Fields::Unit => {
                panic!()
            }
        },
        _ => panic!()
    };
 
    let fields_mapped_iter = IterMapped::new(
        fields_iter,
        Box::new(|field| BuilderField::Mandatory(field)),
    );

    let ref ty_generics = ty_generics_temp;
    let ref builder_struct_name = Ident::new(
        &format!("{}Builder", struct_name),
        proc_macro2::Span::call_site(),
    );

    let mut builder_data = BuilderData {
        struct_name,
        builder_struct_name,
        ty_generics,
        fields_mapped_iter,
    };

    TokenStream::from(quote!())
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "derive_builder"
version = "0.0.0"
edition = "2018"
autotests = false
publish = false

[lib]
proc-macro = true

[dependencies]
syn = "1.0.48"
quote = "1.0.7"
proc-macro2 = "1.0.24"
```

Running it produces the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> builder/src/lib.rs:58:35
   |
58 |       let ref builder_struct_name = Ident::new(
   |  ___________________________________^
59 | |         &format!("{}Builder", struct_name),
60 | |         proc_macro2::Span::call_site(),
61 | |     );
   | |_____^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
71 |   }
   |   -
   |   |
   |   temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |   borrow might be used here, when `fields_mapped_iter` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `IterMapped<BuilderField<'_>, syn::punctuated::Iter<'_, syn::data::Field>>`
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

I don't understand why dropping `builder_struct_name`'s temporary effects `fields_mapped_iter`. Those two are separate fields.

If I change `BuilderData` to use lifetime `'b`, the code compiles and works correctly:

```rust
struct BuilderData<'a, 'b> {
    struct_name: &'a Ident,
    builder_struct_name: &'a Ident,
    ty_generics: &'a TypeGenerics<'a>,
    fields_mapped_iter: IterMapped<BuilderField<'b>, syn::punctuated::Iter<'b, Field>>,
}
```

☝️Changing `BuilderData` to this makes the code work.

If I rearrange the order in which the struct fields were declared and move `let ref builder_struct_name = …` before setting of `fields_iter` and `fields_mapped_iter` it works because those 2 are then dropped before `builder_struct_name`'s temp. Why do their destructors rely on `builder_struct_name`'s temp?

Comment: Here's a very stripped down version on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ead5b56e410577438a6ce0ec484a0fb). Hope I didn't reduce too much. I can't even guess why this error occurs.

Comment: Even more interesting, your full example compiles if you pull out the `format!(...)` into a variable before using it. Very strange.

Comment: @kmdreko, yes, confused with this too. There doesn't seem to be any correlation between the 2 fields. Just giving them same lifetime makes them depend on each other for "some" reason which I don't understand. Noticed now, using a `'static` str at place of `format!()` also makes the code compile. For some reason, `fields_mapped_iter` is depending on the str slice passed to ident.

Comment: Also, thanks for the short example, would really help testing more.

Answer (score 1):

When a scope ends, variables are dropped in reverse of the order in which they were declared.  Hence `BuilderData`'s lifetime parameter `'a` cannot extend beyond when `builder_struct_name` is dropped to the full life of `fields_mapped_iter`.  However, [`syn::punctuated::Iter`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.48/syn/punctuated/struct.Iter.html)
requires that its type argument `T` outlives its
lifetime argument `'a`.

Comment: But why isn't `fields_mapped_iter` effected by `struct_name` then? If I remove `builder_struct_name` completely from the above code, `struct_name` still has the same semantics as `builder_struct_name` in terms of type and lifetime. But in this case, code will compile fine.

Comment: I tried moving `struct_name` after `fields_mapped_iter` and it still works([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e46d88ae9738830a944bbe4b22c476d3)).

Comment: @Mihir:  Ah yes, but `struct_name` borrows from `derive_input` and so the reference has its lifetime.

Comment: It did start to make some sense, but then, in the above code `syn::punctuated::Iter<>`'s T is `syn::Field` which does doesn't have any lifetime params. So isn't `syn::Field: 'a` satisfied anyways as it doesn't contant any references? Referring [Lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds) `T: 'a means that all lifetime parameters of T outlive 'a`

Comment: In this short reproducible [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c9cb5a08ccd7fda581dec1d7fa8f5c0) as well, no bounds (T: 'a) are specified, but error still persists.

Comment: Actually, it makes sense but don't understand if T:'a has any role in it. Will weite some examples snippets and try to understand. Thanks